# In my database is every hourly automatic shutdown how to resolve it?

Tags: oracle

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [13013], [5001], [267], [8485192], [0], [8485192], [17], [], [], [], [], []
Incident details in: d:\app\administrator\diag\rdbms\oracle\oracle\incident\incdir_180293\oracle_smon_6004_i180293.trc
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing logging scn->time mapping.
SMON encountered 11 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
```

Comment: [Check](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600), [try](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Adrci)

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00600 = Oracle (internal) bug = contact Oracle Support.

Meanwhile, search Metalink (My Oracle Support), maybe you'll find something useful.